# The type or namespace name could not be found although it does exist

Tags: c#, dll

I have a project that gives me an error although i do have the reference added, it was working fine before,  then it stopped working after I removed it and re-added it to the project.

http://prntscr.com/2jw29b

I've removed the .dll and re-added it multiple times with no success. please help.

Comment: Did you change **.Net framework** of your projects recently ?

Comment: no i have'nt changed that. all i did was remove the .dll then add it again

Comment: just check the target framework of your project and referenced project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the reference in the main application? if not add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the reference in the solution hierarchy and re-add it with the physical location of the .dll file for the PS3Lib? Maybe the location of the reference is messed up.